# Ubuntu installation - the attempt to mount a file system failed

Tags: windows-8, filesystem

When installing Ubuntu, right after partitioning, I get the following error:

```
the attempt to mount a file system with type ntfs in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #4 (sda) at /windows failed.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?
I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows 8.

Comment: what are you doing like installing alongside windows or in seperate drive

Comment: Alongside windows

Comment: then don't do it make a partition using windows with space like 100 GB or atleast 50GB and install ubuntu on that partition

Comment: Just don't mount Windows, get rid of `/windows` and proceed, or quit the installer and start again.

Comment: That worked! How to I mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just don't mount Windows, get rid of /windows and proceed, or quit the installer and start again.

This worked.